# TOR service not really working

Tags: networking, permissions, tor

I've just installed tor via apt, and it seems that service is working fine:

```
$ sudo service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-06-13 19:04:12 UTC; 12min ago
  Process: 8050 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8050 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service

Jun 13 19:04:11 NanoPi-NEO systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Jun 13 19:04:12 NanoPi-NEO systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

but in running processes I can't see it:

```
$ ps -aux | grep /usr/bin/tor
michail  10962  0.0  0.1   4140   536 pts/0    S+   19:16   0:00 grep --color=auto /usr/bin/tor
```

On the other hand, my mate did the same thing on his machine, and service also seems bo be run:

```
$ sudo service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-02-11 17:28:03 CET; 2 years 4 months ago
 Main PID: 676 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service

Feb 11 17:28:03 odroid64 systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Feb 11 17:28:03 odroid64 systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

but also he can see it running ps:

```
$ ps -aux | grep /usr/bin/tor
debian-+   988  0.1  2.0  42804 35752 ?        Ss   18:32   0:16 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
szklarz  10098  0.0  0.0   6772   900 pts/8    S+   21:16   0:00 grep --color=auto /usr/bin/tor
```

Finally, tor service on my occ isn't really running till I star it typing command:

```
$sudo tor
```

I assume it is caused by some permission issues, but which one? Could you please help?

```
$ ps -A | grep tor
   67 ?        00:00:00 file-storage
  484 ?        00:00:00 rpimonitord
  492 ?        00:00:00 rpimonitord
  493 ?        00:00:00 rpimonitord
 1637 ?        00:00:00 (tor)

$ sudo netstat -anutp | grep tor
michail@NanoPi-NEO:~$
```

Comment: What if `ps -A | grep tor` and `sudo netstat -anutp | grep tor`

Comment: Seems like something is missing below ...

Answer (score 0):

This work 100%:

```
sudo apt install -y tor

sudo apt install -y apparmor-utils
sudo aa-complain system_tor
sudo service tor@default restart 
sudo service tor@default status
```

Comment: And try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/903341/841009